# Array, eliminar valor

Tags: array, assembly

Boa tarde, alguém consegue arranjar alguma dica para um exercicio no qual é necessário percorrer um array e caso encontre um certo valor o elimine do array, isto em assembly. Alguma dica?

Answer (score 1):

Não entendo muito de assembly mas pode ser feito assim:

```
   str1    Array   1,2,4,7,67,99,100,323,421,10

   start:
       call    Deletar
       call    Crlf
       call    Crlf
       call    esperarMsg

   Deletar Proc
       mov     esi, offset str1 
       mov     ecx, 10

   PrintArray:
       mov     eax, [esi]
       call    WriteDec
       mov     eax, " "
       call    WriteChar

   NextNum:
    add     esi, 4
    loop    PrintArray

   Done:    
    ret
Deletar endp
```